# asp.net on postback page title meta description not updating

Tags: asp.net, postback, meta-tags, linkbutton, page-title

There is a asp:LinkButton on asp.net web page. On click I am changing the page title and adding meta description, but it is not updating and reflecting in page view source.

Page title and meta description only updating when page is Not PostBack

Is this by design or any workaround other then using asp:HyperLink

Edited : Added code

```
    protected void lnk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlMeta meta = new HtmlMeta();
        meta.Name = "description";
        meta.Content = "new descrpition";
        Page.Header.Controls.Add(meta);

        Page.Title = "new title of page";
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: please post the code as well, which you are using to update.

Comment: you should show us your code ...

Comment: code added in original post, please let me know if further information required

Comment: i have tested its updating meta tags and page title. have you written some code for meta tag updation on page load? if yes then post it.

Comment: on Page_Load's --> if (!Page.IsPostBack), the same piece of code setting description and title, then on linkbutton click, I want to update it with different page title and meta description. but after clicking linkbutton, it keeps on showing the original page title and meta description.

Comment: try to use link button instead asp:hyperlink. i think it hasn't any server side event.

Comment: well, i have tested same as you done with link button. its working fine. but not with asp:hyperlink.

Comment: do you mean to use asp:hyperlink instead of asp:linkbutton? i know with hyperlink it is working, but dont want to change current implementation, so is it by design in asp.net that page title and meta description can't be change on postback. Because I want some strong justification to change this implemenation as its a huge application.

Comment: no i was thinking that you are using asp:hyperlink. I recommend to use asp:linkbutton. Its working fine here with asp:linkbutton. updating the meta information.

Comment: can you please share the same code which you are using, let me check this with my test page

Comment: I have posted. Is it helpful for you?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it with asp:linkbutton. working fine.

Setting the meta description and title on `page_load` and  updating it on `linkbutton's click` event.

have a look on my code:

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="link" runat="server" Text="Update Meta Info" 
        onclick="link_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Here i'm posting my code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        HtmlMeta meta = new HtmlMeta();
        meta.Name = "description11";
        meta.Content = "new descrpition11";
        Page.Header.Controls.Add(meta);
        Page.Title = "new title of page11";
    }
}

protected void link_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlMeta meta = new HtmlMeta();
    meta.Name = "description";
    meta.Content = "new descrpition";
    Page.Header.Controls.Add(meta);

    Page.Title = "new title of page";
}
```

Comment: it is not working with me, I think the only difference is I am using UpdatePanel, can you check it with update panel 

  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
            <ContentTemplate>


                <asp:LinkButton ID="link" runat="server" Text="Update Meta Info"
                    OnClick="link_Click"></asp:LinkButton>


            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

Comment: its working. why you have put linkbutton in update panel. according to your code page will still load. Have you tried it without update panel?

Comment: Without updatepanel it is working, basically that updatepanel is in master page, and that master page is being used by number of pages, so removing update panel and creating new master page for that page specifically is not possible. Is it working with you when using Linkbutton inside Updatepanel?

Comment: So far what I found and seems something wrong within rendering (using scriptmanager and updatepanel), so on page_init temporarily I disabled EnablePartialRendering to false as  protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ScriptManager1.EnablePartialRendering = false;
        }......... This is not the proper solution but for timebeing, and looking for proper solution.

Comment: I checked it with  asp:ToolkitScriptmanager, but its not working and same result